# Api with injected Endpoints to Redux RTK query causing "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'baseApi' before initialization"

Tags: typescript, rtk-query

I have a redux RTK app set up and I did setup a service with RTK query. I noticed though that we will need a lot of endpoints and it looks like the recommended way by RTK Query is to use [code splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) to grow the API service. This also went pretty smoothly and fit my case since I needed a `dynamicBaseQuery` for all the app in order to inject the selected language in the link.

However the [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics#configuring-the-store) also suggest adding the API reducer path to the RTK store reducer but as [advanced queries](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#injecting-endpoints) docs states:

> ...apiSlice and extendedApiSlice are the same object, but it can be helpful to refer to the extendedApiSlice object instead of apiSlice here as a reminder to ourselves. (This is more important if you're using TypeScript, because only the extendedApiSlice value has the added types for the new endpoints.)

So this also applied to adding the api reducer to the path since if I only added the baseApiSlice to the reducer I got `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'baseApi' before initialization` on `authApi` which is basically `authApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints...` and `authApi` is used in a normal RTK slice (`AuthSlice`) for adding a matcher

```
  builder.addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled
```

I tried putting them all of them in the reducer (so something like):

```
  reducer: {
      [AuthSlice.name]: AuthSlice.reducer,
      [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
      [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
      [buildingsApi.reducerPath]: buildingsApi.reducer, ...
```

but I got the same error (and this is not advised because I would be basically importing the same `api` 3 times which I also read it can lead to errors).

If I instead just add the `authApi` reducer seems like everything goes smooth and I can even use buildingsApi, but it just doesn't fill right. Additionally if I need to use `addMatcher` on `buildingsApi.endpoints` it will fail again with `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'baseApi' before initialization` .

I'd like to mention that I also added `baseApi` to the store middleware like this: `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(baseApi.middleware)` and I am really out of ideas on how to properly set RTK Query using code splitting and any help in this direction is deeply appreciated.

Thank you very much!

PS: The only option I see is setting separate queries instead of using `code splitting` and just make the `dynamicBaseQuery` exportable. But I don't think this is ideal, and it doesn't seem to be the recommended way by the docs either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else encounters a similar problem, `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'baseApi' before initialization`  is actually a circular dependency error.

In my case I was actually importing the `AuthSlice` in `baseApi` in order to get the user language and add it to `dynamicBaseQuery` . Fixed the circular dependency by using a cookie to get the current language.

The code was working without the `extraReducers` from `AuthSlice` since in this case there was nothing from the slice to the api, but once I added `extraReducers` with `addMatcher(authApi.endpoints` the error would come again.

I found something about this on github but I really had a hard time discovering the circular dependecy